# Fire Simulation completely disappears from scene (2.8)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, physics, smoke-simulation, fire

Im making an Iron Man flying over city sort of clip, and i had perfectly good fire sim yesterday. I woke up today and came back to the project and there is no sim in my renders, viewport, nothing. I looked at my domain material and it looked right. But it's just not existing anymore. maybe I have too much in my scene? Here's some pics to see:[image: Mid-SimulationNoFire]

[image: DomainNodeSetup]

[image: TooBigOfAScene?]

Comment: If I am unable to get it back, I can find another way. I just _really_ like the look of the fire simulation. :|

Comment: Did you bake your smoke simulation?

Comment: I did not. To clarify, it is caching the sim?

Comment: Unless you bake the simulation in *Smoke > Cache* you will have to hit play again to see the simulation. Since this can be computationally intensive and you probably don't want to do that everytime you open the file, you can bake them. This stores the simulation in a file.

Comment: Sweet thanks. That worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bake the simulation in *Smoke > Cache* otherwise it won't be saved to disk. If you don't, the simulation will be recalculated the next time you open the file and play the animation. This can be time consuming, since it would need to be done every time you open the file again. If you already have a cached animation from hitting play, you can also press *Current Cache to Bake* which will stored the cached animation, but not calculate it for the following frames that haven't been simulated yet.

[image]